# How can I store the bit pattern in the register with value

Tags: machine-learning

How can i write instruction in Main memory with using Machine language? I have a problem with righting instruction to store the bit pattern in the register R with value XY. Can anybody solve it?

Comment: Welcome to CS! Your question is not clear, can you give us more context?

Comment: Thank you for making the question clearer. However this is a programming question and is off-topic here. You can try to post it on https://stackoverflow.com/